# Is it true that exists a natural number (zero excluded) that is divisible by every natural number?

Tags: predicate-logic

I have the following formula:

$(\exists x)(\forall y) r(x,y)$

Is this formula true in a model where r(x,y) is a binary predicate interpreted as "x is divisible by y" and the universe is all natural numbers except for zero? Why?

Comment: Why would you think this is true?  It's obviously false if we exclude $0$.  But if we don't exclude $0$ it's not intuitively obvious (but easy) to see that $0$ would be the sole exception and only case where it could be true.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you excluding $0$?

The statement is true for $0$ (because $x*0= 0$ is true for all $x$).

But for any $y\ne 0$ the statement, which is equivalent to state $\frac xy$ is an integer, is obviously false.  What if $y > x$?  Then if $x>0$ we have $0< \frac xy < 1$. What if $y = 2x$.  The we have $\frac x{2x} = \frac 12$.

Comment: But if I understand it correctly, number zero is not divisible by all natural numbers (zero included in this case) since zero cannot be divided by zero, right?

Comment: Um...... I *think* divisibility means "There exists and integer $k$ so that $y*k = x$" and not that that "$\frac xy$ is an integer".  Algebraically $\frac xy$ means $x \cdot$ the multiplicative inverse of $y$ and doesn't really imply "dividing" $y$ into $x$.  But you'll have to consult your text/teacher.  I think it's save to say $0|0$ because $0*0 = 0$. but maybe you are correct.

Comment: Also when you say "excluding 0" do you mean 1) there exist a number (that isn't zero) that is divisible by all numbers [definitely false] or 2) there exists a number that is divisible by all numbers (except zero) [true; that number is zero]?

Comment: I mean an universe of discourse with all the natural numbers, meaning zero included/excluded. (there is not a consensus on that terminology so I explicitly state that just for sure)

Comment: Okay.  If $\mathbb N = \{1,2,3....\}$ then the statement is false.  If $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,3.....\}$ then the statement is true because $x*0 = 0$ so $x|0$ for all $x$ and according to Niven&Zuckerman, for one, divisibility is defined as "there exists an $k$ so that $y*k = x$ then $y|x$".  As a *consequence* if $y\ne 0$ then $\frac xy$ is an integer.  (And if $y=0$ then $x=0$... a trivial exception).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: "I mean an universe of discourse with all the natural numbers, meaning zero included/excluded. "  Ah.... well the statement is true if the universe includes $0$ and false if it doesn't.  I figure you must have seen this in reference to a universe where $0$ was included.